# Animation workflow: how to get good preview FPS

Tags: animation, 3d-view, workflow

This is a topic I haven't yet found a proper answer. What is the "correct" workflow for animation in Blender, so that I would have good enough FPS in the viewport to actually be able to do animation in near, if not 100 % realtime playback? I've found that usually when I try to animate my scenes (e.g. one rigged character, few scene props, no simulations), everything moves so slowly (FPS 5-or-so) that it's really difficult to get good understanding of how the scene will actually look when rendered out in full FPS. I've also noticed that certain modifiers, like subdiv and especially the bevel-modifiers tend to tank the FPS heavily. Disabling these modifiers makes a small difference, but the playback tends to be slow regardless.

I remember seeing some "making of" documentaries of big animation films and in those the artists seem to be using some kind of low-rez version of the characters, props etc, so I was wondering maybe that is what I should be doing? Making a low rez version of each asset and then somehow automatically switch those to the og high rez version during render? But... how.

Do you know any good Blender cloud tutorials or youtube tutorials that would explain this subject to me? The only tutorials I've found only tackle the subject from very limited point of view, talking about how to rig and animate characters and such, and not so much about how to actually build and manage a proper workflow for heavier scenes.

Comment: You can play it in Solid mode / In the Timeline you can choose Playback > Sync > Frame Dropping / You can make a quick render with View > Viewport Render Animation / Also maybe you can make some of your objects lighter? If your mesh is very high poly it will take time to animate...

Comment: what you describe low res and high res was indeed used, for several blender cloud movies, its called proxies in the industry : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168645/linking-a-hi-res-low-res-version-of-a-character-and-controlling-both-with-a-s